# does CPU inference make accuracy lower?

Tags: machine-learning, cpu, text-to-speech

I currently do text-to-speech using tacotron2 and hifi-gan. it working well with GPU but after deploying into server and use CPU to run the model, the result is not as good as before.
so my question is : does inference with CPU lower the model accuracy ?
if yes please kindly explain or send me any reference paper or article.

one more thing , I noticed that when running
`model.cuda().eval().half()`
and save the tacotron2 model , the model size reduce to half and it seem to run find ,so if I use this half-size model , will it lower the accuracy too ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into mixed-precision training [NVIDIA](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/mixed-precision-training-deep-neural-networks/), [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/mixed_precision).

Machine learning doesn't *usually* need high precision floating point.
GPUs & Frameworks can take this into account to speed up training.

However, during deployment the model doesn't take this into account.
The deeper your model, the more this may be an issue because the slight differences add up.